# Prolog separating a list into two other lists

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to read through a list, check an element,if the element is in the KB,do something do it and add it to another list, if it's not in the KB then add it to another, third list.

I keep thinking in terms of procedural logic and can't really get my head around it. This is what I makes sense to me - but it doesn't work...

```
//KB
r([a|X],Y,[gone|X]).
r([c|X],Y,[gone|X]).
r([b|X],Y,[known|X]).
r([d|X],Y,[known2|X]).

simplify([X|List],[X|NW],Result) :-
    r(List,Nw,NewList),
    !,
    simplify2(NewList,Nw,Result).

simplify2([W|Words],Nw,[W|NewWords]) :-
     simplify2(Words,Nw,NewWords).

simplify2([],[],[]).
```

Query:

?- simplify([a,b,c,d,e,f],X,Y).

I want:

```
X = [e,f]  
Y = [gone,known,gone,known2]
```

but the above gives `X = [a|mem_address]` and `Y = [d,e]`.

Comment: Very cryptic. I understand that X is the "unknown" elements. But what is Y?

Comment: Btw, I'm curious how you got a memory address as the tail of a Prolog list!

Comment: Eugene, X is unknown and Y is known! I want to simplify(translate) known terms and remove known noise terms and be left with a list of known terms I can do something with and a separate list of unkown terms that I can 'learn'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first you need to collect the data from the KB (actually, the common term is Database) using `setof`. And then it's simple:

```
r([a|X],Y,[gone|X]).
r([c|X],Y,[gone|X]).
r([b|X],Y,[known|X]).
r([d|X],Y,[known2|X]).

kb(L) :- setof((A,B), r([A|_],_,[B|_]), L).

simplify([], [], []).
simplify([H|T], T1, [H2|T2]) :- 
    kb(L), 
    member((H,H2), L),
    simplify(T, T1, T2).

simplify([H|T], [H|T1], T2) :-
    simplify(T, T1, T2).
```

Comment: This gives all possible lists.

Comment: This is a good example of an error, a tracer can show you no less direct than a clean look at the program. Or trying a goal on the toplevel.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, this makes a lot of sense and is the sort of mathod I'll use - I should have been clearer and said that [gone|X] is actually just X. gone is removed! But I should be able to adjust that based on your help. Really,thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Let's first fix the syntax:

- Rest-of-line comments in Prolog start with `%` not `//`.
- Remove the second argument from `r/3`; it has not purpose.
- `MW` -> `Mw` in `simplify/3`.
- Insert spaces in between arguments (not syntactically incorrect, but slightly challenging to read).

Now let's remove some redundancies:

- In `r/2` you do not really need the list tails.
- Also, we do not need a list in order to state that some term is 'known' or 'gone'.
- `simplify/3` and `simplify2/3` can be merged into the same predicate.

Now let's add some new stuff:

- Declare `r/2` as dynamic. This allows the KB to be altered using `assert/1` and `retract/1`.
- Use consistent naming for variables. E.g., `H` for list head, `T` for list tail, and `L` for (full) list.

We get the following:

```
:- dynamic(r/2).

r(a, gone).
r(c, gone).
r(b, known).
r(d, known2).

simplify([], [], []).
simplify([H|T1], L2, L3):-
  (   r(H, Status)
  ->  L2 = T2,
      L3 = [Status|T3]
  ;   L2 = [H|T2],
      L3 = T3
  ),
  simplify(T1, T2, T3).
```

With the desired behavior:

```
?- simplify([a,b,c,d,e,f],X,Y).
X = [e, f],
Y = [gone, known, gone, known2].
```

Notice how in the above I have performed the following steps:

1. I try to get syntactically valid Prolog.
2. Once the program has valid syntax, I try to simplify it while keeping the behavior stable/intact.
3. Only, when the code is both syntactically valid and simplified, I start altering it in order to achieve the intended behavior.

**Edit**: Thanks to [false](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false) for pointing to non-steadfast behavior. The program was edited accordingly.

Comment: @false Indeed! I was quite surprised by the query succeeding :-( Are there ways to check for steadfastness algorithmically and/or systematically? (I know there are some papers on the subject but they are quite formal.)

Comment: @false [Lau et al. 1999](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0743106698100237/1-s2.0-S0743106698100237-main.pdf?_tid=9bbbcfac-7fee-11e4-b931-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1418162532_90275649a1ebe44eb1f4c5e46a007ab5) is on my to-read list, but it will take me some time to plough through I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you!  I am just sweeping through the examples: Definitely the kind of steadfastness is a bit different. In fact. footnote 3 Note that what we call a 'steadfast logic program' is completely different from what O'Keefe ([33], p. 96) calls a 'steadfast predicate', although we also (need to) use 'steadfast' in the sense of 'unchanging'.

Comment: General remark: There is a 200-bounty from me awaiting new contributors, in particular those below 10k. 3 days left. If there is none, 200 rep would be wasted.

Comment: One more remark: what if there is more than one solution for r(H,Status)?

Comment: Thank you, Wouter. I'm still going to use the original database but your answer has helped me so much in understanding the (my!) original problem and you've clarified the logic very well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @false, in relation to this particular instance - I'm only really interested if there is at least one solution and not how many...

Comment: @Conor: That's not what I asked about: But: If there is more than one solution, are there then several answers, or what shall happen exactly?

Comment: actually, scrap my last comment - there will/should be only one ( or none) answer in the DB...